# Neo4J path results between to nodes passing through n relations [*] are too many and missing?

Tags: neo4j, relationship, graph-databases, database, nosql

I’ve been testing the following query

```
MATCH p=(me)-[*]-(rf)
WHERE me.name = "Filipa" AND rf.name="Anders"
RETURN p
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Looking at the graph, in my understanding, the path should just return 2 direct paths (both with 2 hops) from Filipa to Anders , instead I get 2 extra paths both passing from Anders and looping back to Anders with 2 extra paths going in opposite directions after Anders node.

- Why are those 2 extra paths passing twice at Anders's node included in the results?
- Clearly it has to do with graph theory, what is the topic that deals with this aspects of graphs? A brief explanation is welcomed.

*From my comment: @Christophe Willemsen*

Since I haven’t included a relation direction, 2 paths should be present, instead I just get back one path. Both should be present:

```
(Filipa)->(Dilshad)->(Anders) //this path is present
(Anders)->(Dilshad)->(Filipa) //This path is NOT present, why??
```

Furthermore in the "results" the following paths are included:

```
(Filipa)->(Dilshad)->(Anders)->(Becky)->(Emil)->(Cesar)->(Anderes) //These 2 paths pass 2 times at Anders node. Why??
(Filipa)->(Dilshad)->(Anders)->(Cesar)->(Emil)->(Becky)->(Anderes)
```

The latter 2 paths are both passing twice to Anders’s node, why? This Doesn’t make any sense, if this is the logic we could have **infinite paths**?

Answer (score 2):

There are two points with your query :

1. You match an entire pattern, with * length of relationships, meaning that if he find a path with 2 hops and one with 3 hops you'll get the both in return.
2. You do not specify a direction of your relationship, so he will automatically find at least two paths, one in one way and one in another way.

You can specify relationship directions with an arrow :

```
MATCH p=(me)-[*]->(rf)
```

You can limit the return of the amount of paths to 1 :

```
MATCH p=(me)-[*]->(rf)
WHERE me.name = "Filipa" AND rf.name="Anders"
RETURN p
LIMIT 1
```

You can get the shortest path from me to Anders with the `shortestPath` clause :

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((me)-[*]->(rf))
```

which is automatically limited to one result

Comment: Since I haven’t included a relation direction, 2 paths should be present, instead I just get back one path. Both should be present:
(Filipa)->(Dilshad)->(Anders) and (Anders)->(Dilshad)->(Filipa).
Furthermore in the results there is included just one path of the following:
(Filipa)->(Dilshad)->(Anders)->(Becky)->(Emil)->(Cesar)->(Anderes)
(Filipa)->(Dilshad)->(Anders)->(Cesar)->(Emil)->(Becky)->(Anderes)
The latter 2 paths are both passing twice to Anders’s node, why? This Doesn’t make any sense, if this is the logic we could have infinite paths?